# How to set starting Activity for different screen size in android manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-manifest, screen-size

Is possible to set different starting activity for different screen size?

I have file res/layout-large.xml and this layout is different to res/layout.xml because in layout-large is more buttons etc. and I need start this activity in tablet because for this activity is different source file.

thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to start different activity, use **Fragments**. And base on different screen size load different fragments with their UI and Business Logic

Please check [How to adapt ui](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)

Answer (score 1):

Jedil answer is correct, fragment is better than activity for this. 
If you must use activity, run logic to decide which config you want. Then inflate the corresponding layout file with

```
SetContentView(r.id.layout_you_want_to_use)
```